# Using Crystal Report employee in out time calculation

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have employee attendance software and data like this

```
emp id     Date             Time    
1         15/06/16          08:00 12:30  01:00 08:00        
2         15/06/16          08:00 12:30  01:00 07:30
```

How to calculate total hours in the day using crystal reports?

For example:
emp id 1 on date 15 /06/16 total hours work day is 12 hours
and
emp id 2 on date 15/06/16 total hours work day is 11:30 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a formula:

```
Split(Totext(database.Time)," ")[1]& " "&"in time"&ChrW(13)
Split(Totext(database.Time)," ")[2]& " "&"out time"&ChrW(13)
Split(Totext(database.Time)," ")[3]& " "&"in time"&ChrW(13)
Split(Totext(database.Time)," ")[4]& " "&"out time"
```

Place in detail section

Edit..............

Create a formula and write below code and place after the database field:

Note: Where Database.fieldname contains `08:00 12:30  01:00 08:00` whole string

```
Numbervar starthour;
Numbervar startminute;
Numbervar endhour;
Numbervar endminute;
Numbervar Finalhour;
Numbervar Finalminute;
Numbervar i:=0;



starthour:=(ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[2],":")[1]) - ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[1],":")[1]));
endhour:=(ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[7],":")[1]) - ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[4],":")[1]));
startminute:=(ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[2],":")[2]) - ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[1],":")[2]));
endminute:=(ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[7],":")[2]) - ToNumber(Split(Split({Database.fieldname}," ")[4],":")[2]));

if (startminute+endminute) >=60
Then
(
Finalhour:=(starthour+endhour)+1;
Finalminute:=(startminute+endminute)-60
)
else
(
Finalhour:=(starthour+endhour);
Finalminute:=(startminute+endminute)
)
;

Finalhour&":"&Finalminute
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but when converting into number then error is " string is non numeric"

Comment: results would be 11.5 hours

Comment: Where is numeric conversion? Can you post

Comment: siva..... I want calculated difference between 08:00 to 12:30 is 5:30 and 1:30 to 8:00 is 6:30.   so total hours per day is 12 hours

Comment: so this why I converted to numeric

Comment: Ok so you are doing some arithematuc calculations then can you update the question in detail...will try to help

Comment: Tomorrow I will post my answer

Comment: Sorry I am unable to post answer as I am travelling...give me some time will post by monday